# onchange dropdown value get

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have one drop-down menu but in that id dynamically changes in this scenario how to get selected value in dropdown using On Change function.
In this drop-down id, value changes every refresh how to get particular selected value.

```
<select name="status" id="dropdown_status335281563" size="1" tabindex="-1" title="" style="display: none;">
<option value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="2">Grapees</option>
```

Comment: how can you select from an element that is hidden?

Comment: style="display: none;" and change :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("change", "select[id^='dropdown_status']", function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="status" id="dropdown_status335281563">
<option value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="2">Grapees</option>
</select>

<select name="status" id="dropdown_status33523">
<option value="3">Apple 2</option>
<option value="4">Grapees 2</option>
</select>


<select name="status" id="dropdown_status3">
<option value="5">Apple 3</option>
<option value="6">Grapees 3</option>
</select>


<select name="status" id="dropdown_status99999">
<option value="7">Apple 4</option>
<option value="8">Grapees 4</option>
</select>
```

If I am not wrong, your id suffix to element id will change `dropdown_status` this will constant.

You can take value of this as follows,

```
$("select[id^='dropdown_status']").val();
```

I hope this will help.

Try this example for example, I am taking some sample select options and I am trying to get its value, in single function.

Comment: Check example I have attached

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".dropdown_change").change(function(){
      alert($(this).val());
     });
   });
            </script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="status" id="dropdown_change" class="dropdown_change">
<option value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="2">Grapees</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its wrong because of my id value changes every time

Comment: edit my code check new chenges file on click event on class

Answer (score 0):

Your dynamic number change case try this

```
<select name="status" id="dropdown_status335281563" size="1"
tabindex="-1" title="" onchange="getValue()">
<option value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="2">Grapees</option>
</select>


function getValue(){
alert($("select[id^='dropdown_status']").val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get value on the basis of some other attribute of select box like below:

```
$("select[name='status']").change(function(){

alert($(this).val());

})
```